# MariaDb Query using JSON_EXTRACT on a json object containing a nested array returns different result using or not using WHERE

Tags: json, mariadb

On MariaDb 10.10.2 if I run the following query:

```
select l.Id , 
       json_length(l.Response, '$.Response.Errors') as nErrors, 
       json_extract(l.Response, '$.Response.Errors[*].Reason') as reasons 
from logs l LIMIT 0, 5;
```

I get the following result:

```
+----+---------+-----------------------+
| Id | nErrors | reasons               |
+----+---------+-----------------------+
|  1 |       1 | ["UsernameEmpty"]     |
|  2 |       1 | "UserAlreadyLoggedIn" |
|  3 |       2 | "EmailEmpty"          |
|  4 |       2 | "EmailNotValid"       |
|  5 |       2 | "EmailNotValid"       |
+----+---------+-----------------------+
```

If I run the following query:

```
 select l.Id , 
        json_length(l.Response, '$.Response.Errors') as nErrors, 
        json_extract(l.Response, '$.Response.Errors[*].Reason') as reasons 
from    logs l 
where   id = 3;
```

I get the following results:

```
+----+---------+-----------------------------------+
| Id | nErrors | reasons                           |
+----+---------+-----------------------------------+
|  3 |       2 | ["EmailEmpty", "EmailDoNotMatch"] |
+----+---------+-----------------------------------+
```

Can someone tell me why in the second query I obtain the real result in 'reasons' while the first query returns only one reason? As you can see the only thing that changed is the where clause...

Thank you in advance!

Update:

These are the first 5 rows in the db:

```
+----+---------------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+--------+
| Id | IpAddress     | ElapsedTime | Request                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               | Response                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            | IsArchived | Created                    | LastModified               | UserId |
+----+---------------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+--------+
|  1 | 192.168.230.3 |         280 | {"Body":"{\n  \u0022Email\u0022:            \u0022demo1234@test.com\u0022,\n  \u0022EmailConfirm\u0022:     \u0022demo1234@test.com\u0022,\n  \u0022Username\u0022:         \u0022\u0022,\n  \u0022Password\u0022:         \u0012345678\u0022,\n  \u0022PasswordConfirm\u0022:  \u0012345678\u0022\n}","ByteBody":null,"ContentType":"application/json","Cookies":{},"Headers":{"Accept":"*/*","Connection":"close","Host":"192.168.230.1:5001","User-Agent":"Thunder Client (https://www.thunderclient.com)","Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate, br","Content-Type":"application/json","Content-Length":"188"},"Method":"POST","Path":"/api/users","Query":"","Id":0,"Created":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","LastModified":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","IsArchived":false}                                                                                                                                                | {"Response":{"StatusCode":400,"ByteResponse":null,"ByteContentType":"","Errors":[{"Type":"Validation","Parameters":null,"Class":"","Function":"","Message":"","ProdMessage":"","Reason":"UsernameEmpty","StackTrace":"","UserId":-1,"Username":""}],"Debug":[],"ElapsedTime":0},"Id":0,"Created":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","LastModified":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","IsArchived":false}                                                                                                                                                                     |          0 | 2022-12-24 17:14:46.355917 | 2022-12-24 17:14:46.355917 |     -1 |
|  2 | 192.168.230.1 |          13 | {"Body":"{\r\n  \u0022$id\u0022: \u00221\u0022,\r\n  \u0022Email\u0022: \u0022demo0964657430@test.com\u0022,\r\n  \u0022EmailConfirm\u0022: \u0022demo0964657430@test.com\u0022,\r\n  \u0022Username\u0022: \u0022demo0964657430\u0022,\r\n  \u0022Password\u0022: \u0012345678\u0022,\r\n  \u0022PasswordConfirm\u0022: \u0012345678\u0022\r\n}","ByteBody":null,"ContentType":"text/plain; charset=utf-8","Cookies":{},"Headers":{"Host":"192.168.230.1:5001","Authorization":"Bearer tqdsAR2I/WDzj\u002BRUt7XHSDMz9WQ2Z4Ehekw2ey0QiB/06Z9\u002B0pujjpxn\u002BAG5i1EojpZWfLPaiR1Ybi59Xg\u002BLreCRpI80Uoc0mhxYXw7SpFCsA2x/VH5LByKfM/DUEC84tGpZmRlZk7eBBNLKsWv5/ymLQi95xA2w7p4XYJM72es=","Content-Type":"text/plain; charset=utf-8","Content-Length":"203"},"Method":"POST","Path":"/api/users","Query":"","Id":0,"Created":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","LastModified":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","IsArchived":false} | {"Response":{"StatusCode":400,"ByteResponse":null,"ByteContentType":"","Errors":[{"Type":"Validation","Parameters":null,"Class":"","Function":"","Message":"","ProdMessage":"","Reason":"UserAlreadyLoggedIn","StackTrace":"","UserId":-1,"Username":""}],"Debug":[],"ElapsedTime":0},"Id":0,"Created":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","LastModified":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","IsArchived":false}                                                                                                                                                               |          0 | 2022-12-24 17:20:02.404424 | 2022-12-24 17:20:02.404424 |     -1 |
|  3 | 192.168.230.1 |         214 | {"Body":"{\r\n  \u0022$id\u0022: \u00221\u0022,\r\n  \u0022Email\u0022: \u0022\u0022,\r\n  \u0022EmailConfirm\u0022: \u0022demo1488578354@test.com\u0022,\r\n  \u0022Username\u0022: \u0022demo1488578354\u0022,\r\n  \u0022Password\u0022: \u0012345678\u0022,\r\n  \u0022PasswordConfirm\u0022: \u0012345678\u0022\r\n}","ByteBody":null,"ContentType":"text/plain; charset=utf-8","Cookies":{},"Headers":{"Host":"192.168.230.1:5001","Content-Type":"text/plain; charset=utf-8","Content-Length":"177"},"Method":"POST","Path":"/api/users","Query":"","Id":0,"Created":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","LastModified":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","IsArchived":false}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     | {"Response":{"StatusCode":400,"ByteResponse":null,"ByteContentType":"","Errors":[{"Type":"Validation","Parameters":null,"Class":"","Function":"","Message":"","ProdMessage":"","Reason":"EmailEmpty","StackTrace":"","UserId":-1,"Username":""},{"Type":"Validation","Parameters":null,"Class":"","Function":"","Message":"","ProdMessage":"","Reason":"EmailDoNotMatch","StackTrace":"","UserId":-1,"Username":""}],"Debug":[],"ElapsedTime":0},"Id":0,"Created":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","LastModified":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","IsArchived":false}    |          0 | 2022-12-24 17:26:05.526448 | 2022-12-24 17:26:05.526448 |     -1 |
|  4 | 192.168.230.1 |          45 | {"Body":"{\r\n  \u0022$id\u0022: \u00221\u0022,\r\n  \u0022Email\u0022: \u0022aaa\u0022,\r\n  \u0022EmailConfirm\u0022: \u0022demo1488578354@test.com\u0022,\r\n  \u0022Username\u0022: \u0022demo1488578354\u0022,\r\n  \u0022Password\u0022: \u0012345678\u0022,\r\n  \u0022PasswordConfirm\u0022: \u0012345678\u0022\r\n}","ByteBody":null,"ContentType":"text/plain; charset=utf-8","Cookies":{},"Headers":{"Host":"192.168.230.1:5001","Content-Type":"text/plain; charset=utf-8","Content-Length":"180"},"Method":"POST","Path":"/api/users","Query":"","Id":0,"Created":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","LastModified":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","IsArchived":false}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  | {"Response":{"StatusCode":400,"ByteResponse":null,"ByteContentType":"","Errors":[{"Type":"Validation","Parameters":null,"Class":"","Function":"","Message":"","ProdMessage":"","Reason":"EmailNotValid","StackTrace":"","UserId":-1,"Username":""},{"Type":"Validation","Parameters":null,"Class":"","Function":"","Message":"","ProdMessage":"","Reason":"EmailDoNotMatch","StackTrace":"","UserId":-1,"Username":""}],"Debug":[],"ElapsedTime":0},"Id":0,"Created":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","LastModified":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","IsArchived":false} |          0 | 2022-12-24 17:26:05.626461 | 2022-12-24 17:26:05.626461 |     -1 |
|  5 | 192.168.230.1 |           7 | {"Body":"{\r\n  \u0022$id\u0022: \u00221\u0022,\r\n  \u0022Email\u0022: \u0022aaa@\u0022,\r\n  \u0022EmailConfirm\u0022: \u0022demo1488578354@test.com\u0022,\r\n  \u0022Username\u0022: \u0022demo1488578354\u0022,\r\n  \u0022Password\u0022: \u0012345678\u0022,\r\n  \u0022PasswordConfirm\u0022: \u0012345678\u0022\r\n}","ByteBody":null,"ContentType":"text/plain; charset=utf-8","Cookies":{},"Headers":{"Host":"192.168.230.1:5001","Content-Type":"text/plain; charset=utf-8","Content-Length":"181"},"Method":"POST","Path":"/api/users","Query":"","Id":0,"Created":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","LastModified":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","IsArchived":false}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 | {"Response":{"StatusCode":400,"ByteResponse":null,"ByteContentType":"","Errors":[{"Type":"Validation","Parameters":null,"Class":"","Function":"","Message":"","ProdMessage":"","Reason":"EmailNotValid","StackTrace":"","UserId":-1,"Username":""},{"Type":"Validation","Parameters":null,"Class":"","Function":"","Message":"","ProdMessage":"","Reason":"EmailDoNotMatch","StackTrace":"","UserId":-1,"Username":""}],"Debug":[],"ElapsedTime":0},"Id":0,"Created":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","LastModified":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","IsArchived":false} |          0 | 2022-12-24 17:26:05.642447 | 2022-12-24 17:26:05.642447 |     -1 |
+----+---------------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+--------+
```

Comment: Can you share your input table?

Comment: It looks like a bug introduced, at least, since version 10.9.2 (see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GXDNbQxL)), in version 10.8.4 the bug does not occur (see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5I8zXgqI)). I suggest opening a report in the [MariaDB bugs database](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV).

Comment: Bug reported: [Query using JSON_EXTRACT on a json object containing a nested array returns different result using or not using WHERE](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-30308).